# How can I use the renewed provisioning profile for existing apps?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa, apple-developer

I have developed a couple of applications in iOS. Few days before my provisioning profile got expired. I renewed and downloaded it from apple developer portal. Now my question is how this new profile will get reflected in existing applications? Since there are many applications I won't be able to build it again with a new provisioning profile. So please let me know how to add this new profile with existing applications without a rebuild.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using a free membership then you need to reinstall your app every few days. If you have a paid membership then the app will,operate for several months

Comment: It is paid one. And Applications were working from last year. Before few days account and profile got expired. We renewed the account and provisioning profile. But now how to update my existing applications with this new profile without rebuild ?

Comment: Are these enterprise apps or ad-how builds under a personal/organisational programme membership?  If they are enterprise builds then you can use an MDM to push the new provisioning profile. If you dont distribute via MDM or they are ad-hoc non-enterprise builds then you will need to rebuild the app and reinstall

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you paul. It is ad-hoc, So I need to rebuild and reinstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what kind of builds you're concerned about:

- App Store: expired provisioning profiles don't affect builds that have been downloaded from the App Store. You don't need to make a new build with the provisioning profile. You will, however, need to use the new provisioning profile if you update the app on the App Store.
- Ad Hoc: builds will stop running if the provisioning profile used to create them has expired. You will need to make new builds and distribute them again.
- Enterprise: you can update the profiles using the MDM protocol. See the "Provisioning Profiles Can Be Installed Using MDM
  " section in the [MDM Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/MDM-Protocol-Reference.pdf).

Comment: FWIW from what I understand the reason for halting non app store builds through expiration of existing provision profiles is to: **give more control to** to app owner/organization/developers e.g. if the organization built apps for its employees on their _personal_ phone, but then fired an employee. How can the organization make sure its fired employee no longer has access to the app? (Surely they can disable his logins access. Yet he can use the app for whatever part it doesn't require login.) **Solution:** expire previous provisioning profiles and direct _existing_ employees to download again

Comment: Thank you guys. Yeah it is Ad-hoc.This will take consider time of my day, anyhow no options  I have to rebuild and reinstall all applications.